# The "delete" option has disappeared for me in comments

Tags: bug, status-norepro, comment

Something odd has happened for me recently:  The "delete" option on comments has, with sporadic exceptions, disappeared for me, as has the edit option.  I'm also for the most part no longer seeing timestamps on comments.  Here's a screenshot from this morning:

[image]

Oddly, my second comment here *does* show the timestamp and edit options.  It also gave me the delete option, but it was really the first comment I would have deleted if I could.  (I try to remove comments that are no longer relevant, so as to reduce the clutter.)

Does anyone have any idea why this is happening?  Is it just me?

**Update**:  If it helps identify where the problem is, I'm running Safari 6.0.5 on a 16-month-old MacAir running OSX 10.8.4.

Comment: Are you on a mobile device? (Also, people will want to know what browser you are using, etc.) Pesonally, I do not have this problem. Although I only see the delete button when I am hovering over it.

Comment: @user1729, I'm using Safari on a 16-month-old MacAir laptop.  I only noticed this problem a couple of days ago.

Comment: @user1729, the delete button no longer appears for me when I hover over where it should be.  (I'm having the same edit/delete/timestamp problem here.  Otherwise I could have edited my last comment in response to your edit of yours!)

Comment: Does this happen when you review posts (low quality, new etc.) or when you view posts normally? How comments work exactly seems to depend on it although I'm not entirely sure how.

Comment: Have you tried to clear the cache?

Comment: @CareBear, done.

Comment: @BarryCipra can you repro on our main site (stackoverflow.com) or just on math.so?

Comment: @Haney, I'm not sure what "repro" means, but a quick look at stackoverflow.com suggests I would have the same problem there -- i.e., I see a few timestamps on comments, but not very many.  (Oddly, I was allowed to edit this comment, but not any of my previous comments here.  This happened elsewhere also, and seems to be transient.  I probably won't be able to edit this comment again (Oor maybe not, as this second edit shows!).)

Comment: @BarryCipra sorry, "repro" is reproduce in programmer slang I suppose. Forgot we're on math for a minute. :) Let me dig into this a bit.

Comment: @Haney, thanks.  It could just be my machine being squirrelly.  But it's a weirdly specific thing to be squirrelly about.

Comment: @BarryCipra dumb question, but it's not a touch device is it? It has a mouse?

Comment: @Haney, it has a tracking pad just below the keyboard.  I don't touch the screen. (And once again, it gave me the edit option for this one comment, along with the delete option and a timestamp.  But just for this one comment.)

Comment: If this bug persists, you should run for moderator, then you can delete all comments. Including your own. It would be a great campaign slogan "I just wanted to delete a comment of mine six months ago..." :-)

Comment: @AsafKaragila, of "If elected, you won't ever hear from me again...."

Comment: The fact that you can not **edit** your comments for a long time is expected and by design; editing comments is only possible for the first 5 mins after posting.

Comment: @quid, I'm aware of that.  But with aforementioned exceptions, I'm generally unable to edit even immediately (else I would have changed the typo "of" or "or" in my reply to Asaf).  But it's mainly the inability to delete comments that concerns me.

Comment: @quid, I'm aware of the "hover" aspect too.  I discussed it with user1729 at the top of the comments here. (And once again the stackexchange gods gave me the edit/delete option here, along with a timestamp, at least for the moment!)

Comment: Sorry! I missed that. I will delete that comment.

Comment: @quid, that's OK.  I would delete my reply too, but I can't!!! (It let me edit this comment, though.)

Answer (score 1):

I wish I had a better answer for you, but unfortunately after a few hours of investigation I cannot reproduce this issue at all. The hover effect is done via CSS, so I checked for some issues with Safari 6.0.5 around that, and while some exist, there's no practical way for me to verify that they are the cause of your problems. I'd suggest trying another browser, such as Firefox, to see if the hover effect on comments works correctly in said browser, and if so, possibly upgrading or reinstalling Safari and/or systematically disabling plugins and extensions. Sorry that I cannot be of more help on this one.